# Make a Kafka private when it is created in the ACLS

Tags: security, apache-kafka

I have a Kafka cluster with zookeeper and Kafka security manager (KSM). KSM helps with Kafka ACLs (https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-security-manager).

When a topic is created, it becomes automatically public if no permissions entry are in the Kafka ACL.

How can I make a topic private when it gets created in Kafka?
Thank you

Comment: I removed the "accessibility" tag as that is to do with making things accessible for people with disabilities and doesn't seem to apply here, I hope you don't mind. If that is wrong and this question does cover accessibility as defined in the tag description then re-add it and my apologies!

Comment: Thank you! I meant accessibility to data.